# AndroidHttpClient cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to Android development (just started today), and also very new to Java development, although I've been programming C# for several years.

I'm trying to make an HTTP request using the  [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html), but my code won't even compile.

Eclipse simply highlights the line of code and says, `AndroidHttpClient cannot be resolved to a type`.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.net.*;
import android.net.http.*;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AndroidHttpClient client = new AndroidHttpClient();
    }
}
```

I started with an empty Android project after installing the Android SDK and the ADT. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which API target do you have within your project? `AndroidHttpClient` is only for API Level 8 <.

If you want to target lower versions of Android you could look at [`HttpClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) and check if that tool meets your requirements.

Comment: That fixed it! In the properties for my project, I had checked Android 2.1. When I changed to Android 2.2, it fixed the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I don't want to sound like a smart-ass, but your answer is in the second sentence of the documentation :) :

```
Don't create this directly, use the newInstance(String) factory method.
```

Comment: I won't hold it against you, but the Java compiler doesn't give an unresolved type error for calling a constructor that isn't available. It gives a "constructor is not visible" error. The problem was that I had targeted the wrong API version.